# How to pronounce Louisville?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

How would I phonetically spell the way locals pronounce Louisville?

(Louisville, KY)

Comment: The locals pronounce it in more than one way: http://www.wdrb.com/story/25835424/how-to-properly-pronounce-louisville

Comment: This appears to be a viable answer. Any interest in writing it as such?

Comment: It depends on which side of Louisville you're from.  But definitely not "looey-ville".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're speaking of the Louisville in Kentucky, when I was last in those parts it was pronounced approximately /ˈlʊ<sup>ə</sup>vl̩ /, with a syllabic /l/ and the first syllable just barely a diphthong. The one in Tennessee has a more definite diphthong: /ˈlʊivl̩ /.

Comment: Not all residents have a southern accent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What's the Unicode for that l̩?

Comment: The _combining vertical line below_ is U+0329. (I just look it up in the Character Viewer. Still haven’t gotten around to including it in a custom keyboard layout …)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you. I didn't know about the combining characters.

Comment: This is a good answer.  The comment from @choster offers two slightly variant pronunciations.  I can't quite tell if they are the same as you've described, can you confirm?

Comment: @Minnow Mine's the LOO-A-VUL version, but there ain't much -A- there. And seems to me that for most folks in Tennessee and Kentucky -ville is pronunced with markedly less stress than elsewhere, and with a vowel reduced however far you can manage.

Comment: I would say "loo-uh-vul", with the "uh" mostly swallowed.  Unless you're talking about the one in Colorado.